# How Can I Make My 404 Error Call My Custom 404 Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I found solutions telling me to use something like this (in system.web) to a make custom error page:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/home">
  <error redirect="~/home/page_not_found" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
```

and this (in system.webServer):

```
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="Error404.html" responseMode="File" />
    <error statusCode="500" path="Error.html" responseMode="File" />
  </httpErrors>
```

I tried both of these methods and none of them seemed to work. I'm not sure if I have to delete things in in `system.web` and `system.webServer, or if I'm suppose to make Routes to the controller in which I want the error messages to be displayed in, so I am going to show you what I have

**Web.config:**

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules>
    <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
    <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

**web.config:**

```
<system.web>
  <compilation>
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
</system.web>
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  <handlers>
    <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
    <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

**HomeController:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...
    [Route("~/page_not_found")]
    public ActionResult PageNotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return View();
    }
    [Route("~/internal_server_error")]
    public ActionResult InternalServerError()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        return View();
    }
}
```

My question is this: "What do I do to get my program to redirect to the error pages using the solution above?"

Side Note: if you need my Route.Config, here it is:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 404 specific, none the less:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error"></customErrors>
```

You can toggle the On to Off above.

To test, in your controller action:

```
throw new Exception();
```

In Views, Shared, create Error.cshtml

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}

<h1 class="text-danger">Error.Custom.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
```

Comment: 1) you can make your customErrors web.config element like mine to start
2) remove the httpErrors element to start
3) remove anything else related to this from your web.config
4) remove actions in homecontroller
5) remove special registerroutes
6) If you can get a custom error page, please tell me if this advances your cause at all, if so,
then we can add back other pieces, although I am not sure it will work on my machine.  If this does
not further your cause, then please entertain other answers

Comment: There is, apparently, a web.config Debug and a web.config Release. I didn't know that until now -_- Anyway, should I be using one of those for the code?

Comment: use the debug, release is for pushing to production without the .pdb debugging files, and other hooks into the debugger that you don't need in production

Answer (score 0):

In `webconfig` in `<system.webServer>` add

```
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Error404" />
    </httpErrors>
```

After that create `ErrorController` and add the folowing action:

```
public ActionResult Error404()
 {
    return View();
 }
```

After that create your custom `Error404.cshtml` view in Errors folder

Comment: In the Web.Debug file?

Comment: Just in the Web.config file. You can find it in a root folder of WebApplication project.

Comment: What about     
`<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>` Do I* remove that?

Comment: Do not remove anything. Just add the code I wrote to <system.webServer> tag. You can add this after the <modules></modules> tag.

Comment: Does the Error404 Action have to be routed in Route.config for this to work?

Comment: Do I have to create an error controller or can I use a home controller?

Comment: You don't have to change anything in Route.config. Also, you can create Error404 Action in Home Controller, but I would suggest that you create separate Error Controller.